# Did Blade also have vampiric mental powers?

Tags: marvel, vampire, blade

Rewatched Blade 2 the other day. The second to last fight when Blade falls in the blood pool, he recovers and is at full power defeating all the security guard. Afterwards Reinhardt tries to kill him with a sword. Blade catches the sword swiftly, to the point of hyper vibration. Reinhardt is stunned as Blade looks into his eyes.

I know the Reapers could cause terror to the Vampires. I am just asking if anyone knows for certain if Blade had any mental/psychic abilities or not, especially while at full power?

Comment: I don't remember the vampires from that universe having mental powers in general?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, in Blade 1 when the camera focuses on the human characters often times they act like their eyes are playing games on them. I know the Reapers could appear and reappear, playing mental games with the Vampire squad. But I guess the comics may be a different story. I wish I knew more.

Comment: I don't recall Reapers having any such ability, and [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Reapers_(Earth-26320)) doesn't mention it either.

Comment: To me it looked like a simple contest of strength between two angry men trying to control a single weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Blade_II_David_goyer.html) makes no mention whatsoever of Blade having any kind of *mental superpowers*.

> REINHARDT:
>   The vampire mercenary clutches Blade's sword in his hand,
>   but the weapon provides him with little sense of security given that
>   he's just seen a dozen of his men slaughtered.  The automatic
>   sprinkler system is on now, spraying water down upon Blade and
>   Reinhardt alike.  Blade advances.
>
> Reinhardt's been cornered.  There's nowhere else for him to run. 
>   Refusing to be cowed, Reinhardt SCREAMS and brings the sword down at
>   Blade's head when WHOOSH -
>
> But Blade swings his hands upward, slapping them on either side of the
>   blade, trapping the sword on its downward arc.
>
> **Reinhardt strains, trying to tear the sword away from Blade's grip. 
>   The vampire's eyes widen in fear.  And during that split-second in
>   which the two men are frozen, connected by the weapon which vibrates
>   between them, Blade says:**
>
> **BLADE** *Tell me something, chief.  Can you blush?*
>
> TWHISH!  The sword twists free from Reinhardt's grasp, spinning upward
>   into the air.  Reinhardt stumbles backwards against the blood cask
>   railing as --
>
> Blade catches the sword on its way down, swinging it around in one
>   fluid motion, slicing Reinhardt's torso in half, along with a diagonal
>   axis!  Reinhardt sinks to his knees as the TWO HALVES split apart,
>   turning to ash before they hit floor.
>
> Beat.  Blade stands beneath the spray of the overhead sprinklers,
>   rinsing the blood from his body.  He turns towards the exit, sword in
>   hand.

Reinhardt appears to be terrified by Blade's martial prowess, not any sort of mental voodoo.

Comment: Love this anaylisis. Thanks. Sounds good to me. I was just so focused on Blade's calmness during his interaction. And I had no idea it was originally in the script for Reinhardt to be split in two halves. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Vampires in the films are more so created through an advanced retrovirus. That's why Blade mentioned to Karen that crosses and holy water "don't do dick" in the first film. They aren't at all supernatural in nature and as such, lack the more mystical aspects and abilities.